# Custom page 404 for nginx

Tags: nginx

I thought it was easy, but I have question - How can I use custom page as response code 404?
There is one part from my config which I want use with custom file 404.html.

```
server {
       listen 81;
       server_name *.my_site.ru;
       return 404 ;
       error_page 404 /404.html;
       location = /404.html {
       root /etc/nginx;
       internal;
        }
}
```

there is my html file  /etc/nginx/404.html.
But these don't work. I always have default nginx's page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `return` statement inside a `location` block. The following works as expected:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        return 404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /etc/nginx;
        internal;
    }
}
```